# How to know if Node.JS Mysql connection is ended or not

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-connection

in other VPS, I have a remote database service and it restarts every morning at 6:00. Unfortunately, this causes an instant MySQL connection to close. Is there any way to know if the connection is ended ?

Like :

```js
connection.isEnd();
```

I connect to my database without pooling connection.
Exemple :

```js
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
                host     : _this.config.mysql.database.ip,
                user     : _this.config.mysql.database.username,
                password : _this.config.mysql.database.password,
                database : _this.config.mysql.database.db
            });

            connection.connect(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
                    return;
                }
                _this.bdd = connection;
                resolve(_this);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some reason to avoid pooling? The pool code automatically provides [resilience](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#server-disconnects) against database server reboots, connection timeouts, and temporary network faults. All those things happen unpredictably.

You can detect a dead connection by running some trivial SQL statement like `SELECT 1` and catching exceptions. But why build that and debug it when the connection pool will do it for you?

Comment: No. It was just for information purposes. If we need to change the connection mode, I will do it as soon as possible in order to succeed.
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method in node.js, that provides you to know, did the connection close.
Probably, you can just reconnect to your server and when it is turned down, you have an error -> No connection with a server.